# Images are spilling out of table

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I'm having trouble with a homework...
I am quite new to `HTML/CSS` and I can't find a fix to my images spilling out of my table... no matter the sizes of my pictures, they still won't fit in the table cells...

Table image:

[image]

```
<div class="section1 center">
 <p class="section1Text">
  Pamela Holland is a University of Melbourne trained Clinical 
   Psychologist practicing in Melbourne's far southeastern suburbs and West 
   Gippsland who specializes in the delivery of scientifically supported 
   cognitive-behavioral therapies (CBT) to adults and older adolescents 
   experiencing emotional difficulties.
 </p>

 <table style="position:absolute;z-index:6;color:white;font- 
  size:13px;top:145px;left:160px;">

    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/bullets.png" width="15px"></td>
        <td>8 years of experience</td>
        <td><img src="images/bullets.png" width="15px"></td>
        <td>Full confidentiality</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/bullets.png" width="15px"></td>
        <td>Modern and effective methods of psychotherapy</td>
        <td><img src="images/bullets.png" width="15px"></td>
        <td>My office is located in city center</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<img src="images/owner.png" width="700px">

<div class="dividerTransparency center">
    <p>gsasga</p>
</div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.section1 {
width:50%;
background-color:#aba89d;
position:relative;
}

.section1Text{
z-index:5;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
width:60%;
font-size:13px;
color:white;
top:70px;
left:210px;
 }

.dividerTransparency {
width:100%;
height:42px;
background-color:rgba(103,101,96,.5);
position:relative;
z-index:3;

}

.section1 img {
margin-left:50px;
position:relative;
bottom:-45px;
z-index:2;
}
```

I hope this is okay.. I dont know an easier way to share the code here since I am quite new...

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below css.

```
table tr td img{
    bottom:auto;}
```

It's work for me.